# Getting CurrentRecord on a dynamic recordset on Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, record

I have this code for setting the value for an unbound textbox control, which I call txtCurrRec.  It's to display "x of y records" on a form, instead of relying on the navigation control record count.  Problem is I set the control source for the form, based on a toggle button.  By default (on load) the toggle is true and the filter is on.  If the toggle is pressed a function determines what the sql is and what the txtCurrRec should be.  It gets the total records right (the y of that statement) but if the form is using the filtered SQL (an int field = -1) the x value shows the record count based on the table values, not the filtered set.

This is the public function code:

```
Private Function ABOnly()
Dim pSQL As String

If Me.tgABRec = True Then
    Me.tgABRec.Caption = "AB Recs Only"
    Me.tgABRec.BackColor = RGB(221, 217, 195)
    Me.tgABRec.HoverColor = RGB(221, 217, 195)
    pSQL = "SELECT * From tblAllRecs WHERE ABRecs = -1"
    Me.txtCurrRec = CStr(Me.CurrentRecord) & " of " & _
    DCount("ID", "tblAllRecs", "ABRecs = -1") & " Records"
Else
    Me.tgABRec.Caption = "ALL RECORDS SHOWING"
    Me.tgABRec.BackColor = RGB(221, 217, 195)
    Me.tgABRec.HoverColor = RGB(221, 217, 195)
    pSQL = "SELECT * From tblAllRecs"
    Me.txtCurrRec = CStr(Me.CurrentRecord) & " of " & _
    DCount("ID", "tblAllRecs") & " Records"
End If

End Function
```

It is the CStr(Me.CurrentRecord) that seems to not work properly with the dynamic SQL. Does anyone know how I can get that to work properly?

Comment: What is `Me.CurrentRecord` supposed to be referencing? Perhaps something on a form (like a text box) or something else? I ask because generally speaking `Me.CurrentRecord` is used by Microsoft Access to call the property and set it to an Integer value that represents the current record number displayed on a form.

Comment: it should be the current form

Comment: Well, if the record you are referring to is directly on the main form, there should not be any issue. However, if this is a subform, it could explain the problems you are having. For any subform you would need to reference the `CurrentRecord` differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the main part.

```
Me.RecordSource = pSQL
```

You need to assign the record set source before you can use `me.currentRecord`

Comment: I thought I had assigned that elsewhere, but you are right.